# Database could not open after insert some contact from PhoneBook in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sqlite, ios7, ios8

Database Could not able to open after insert few record from iPhone Contact and application UI  irresponsive and crash

```
-(BOOL)InsertUserBirtdayInfo:(UserBirthDayInfo*) objBirthDayInfo
{
isOperationCompleted=NO;
@try
{
    if ( sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &calledDB, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        statementInsert = nil;

        NSString *insert=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ (%@, %@ ,%@, %@ ,%@ ,%@ , %@ , %@ ,%@ ,%@ ,%@, %@,%@) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",_Table,_Name,_Phone,_UserImage,_Birthday_Day,_Birthday_Month,_Birthday_Year,_isDisplayOnCalender,_isMessageDefault,_Default_Message,_Custom_Message,_isAutoPost,_isTextMessage,_isFacebook];
        const char *qryInsert = [insert UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(calledDB, qryInsert, -1, &statementInsert, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(calledDB));
        }else{

            sqlite3_bind_text(statementInsert, 1, [objBirthDayInfo.Name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statementInsert, 2, [objBirthDayInfo.Phone UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            NSData *dataForImage = objBirthDayInfo.User_Image;
            sqlite3_bind_blob(statementInsert,3, [dataForImage bytes],(int) [dataForImage length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            sqlite3_bind_int(statementInsert,4, objBirthDayInfo.BirthDay_Day.intValue);
            sqlite3_bind_int(statementInsert,5, objBirthDayInfo.BirthDay_Month.intValue);
            sqlite3_bind_int(statementInsert,6, objBirthDayInfo.BirthDay_Year.intValue);

            sqlite3_bind_int(statementInsert,7,(int) objBirthDayInfo.isDisplayCalender);
            sqlite3_bind_int(statementInsert,8,(int)objBirthDayInfo.isMessageDefault);

            sqlite3_bind_text(statementInsert,9, [objBirthDayInfo.defaultMessage UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statementInsert,10, [objBirthDayInfo.customMessage UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
           // sqlite3_bind_int(statementInsert,11,(int) objBirthDayInfo.isNotification);
            sqlite3_bind_int(statementInsert, 12,(int) objBirthDayInfo.isAutoPost);
            sqlite3_bind_int(statementInsert, 13,(int) objBirthDayInfo.isTextMessage);
            sqlite3_bind_int(statementInsert, 14,(int) objBirthDayInfo.isFacebook);

            if(sqlite3_step(statementInsert)==SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                isOperationCompleted=YES;
                NSLog(@"User birthdate information inserted successfully on database!");

            }

            else
            {

                NSLog(@"Failed to Insert User birthdate information!");
            }

        }

    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Insert Record");

        NSLog(@"Failed to open database with error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(calledDB));
    }

}


@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    isOperationCompleted=NO;
    NSLog(@"%@",exception);
}
@finally
{
   sqlite3_reset(statementInsert);
    sqlite3_close(calledDB);
}
return isOperationCompleted;
}
```

Comment: I'd also suggest making `statementInsert` and `isOperationCompleted` local variables to avoid unintended consequences. There's no reason for making them instance variables.

Comment: You've got 13 variables to bind to which means you should be binding variables with indexes from 0 through to 12. You have from 1 through to 14. So binding to index 13 and 14 is certainly going to be a problem. You also need to `sqlite3_finalize()` to release your statement.

Comment: You can check that all of your `sqlite3_bind_xxx()` functions return `SQLITE_OK` to make sure that your statement is properly ready. `SQLITE_RANGE` is returned if the index is out of range: [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)

Comment: Additional code has leaks: Bottom line, any Core Foundation that includes `Copy` or `Create` in the name is returning an object that you're responsible for releasing. So, either use `__bridge_transfer` or `CGBridgingRelease` (at which point ARC will take care of the memory for you), or make sure to call `CFRelease` when you're done with the object. Run the code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu) and it will point these out to you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't just skip column 11. If you don't want to bind a value to it, use `sqlite3_bind_null`. But given that you only have 13 columns and you're binding using indexes up to 14, I'm presuming you removed `isNotification`, so perhaps you want to renumber indexes 12-14 to be 11-13? Bottom line, check the result of the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` calls and it would have caught this, methinks.

Also, btw, do not call `sqlite3_reset`. (That's for resetting a prepared statement so that you can bind new values in order to call `sqlite3_step` again.) You should instead use `sqlite3_finalize`.

If you're still having problems, tell us what the exception was. Or if you're not going to share that with us, refer to [My App Crashed, Now What?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1). And I understand why you may have added exception handling, but that's not a preferred error handling mechanism in Objective-C and I'd remove it so that you an see what the full stack trace and full details of the exception in the debugger.

Comment: Hi Rob...Thanks for your response.I made changes but it is still crashing after insert few records.

Comment: Then you have to share the details of the crash. Get rid of exception handling in the code, let it crash, and edit your question, including the particulars of the crash (exact messages, stack trace, etc.). Then try again, this time with an exception breakpoint, and see if it shows you the precise line that's causing the crash. Simply saying "it crashed" doesn't help. You have to narrow it down.

Comment: Hi,I had edit all source code.When I import contact from iPhone address book at that time ,I get could not open databse after insert few record and if click on any table view-row then application crash or any above button.if I comment insert and update contact record database programming  then its working file.so my application crashing due to database insert record issue.

Comment: OK, let's assume that it's crashing "due to database insert record issue." But where precisely? What's causing the crash? If you don't share the details of the crash or do some of the diagnostics I outlined, you won't find out.

Comment: Hi there is not specific row crash issue or any in database insert coding.I am getting
 015-01-02 19:16:36.482 BirthdayXchange[1847:471907] Failed to open database to create Table with error unable to open database file and

Comment: 2015-01-02 19:16:36.513 BirthdayXchange[1847:471792] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BD365D0C-0FC6-4B2E-B538-BAADEAFE84EF/BirthdayXchange.app> (loaded)' with name 'Jyo-7v-LIH-view-fdR-on-jSJ' and directory 'Main.storyboardc' crash issue when click on Tableview didselect row or any other UI button.when I comment database insert/update code its running file without any crash.Actually its giving storyboard wrong error message bit its database issue.

Comment: It's hard to say on the basis of what's been shared, but you are reporting a database error message that would appear to be from some other routine (the text of the error message doesn't match the error messages above). One possible issue is that you're using a class ivar, `calledDB`, which could have unintended consequences (e.g. if you opened the database, then called this that opens and closes db again, then subsequent attempts to use the original `calledDB` would fail). I would use a local variable for the `sqlite3*` pointer you're using here. Always use the narrowest possible scope.

Comment: If that's not it (and it may not be...that was just a random guess based upon the limited information provided, though in the spirit of reducing unintended consequences you should always use the narrowest possible scope for your variables), then I think we need to see the code that is generating these error messages/crashes, not just the `InsertUserBirtdayInfo` routine.